# Как убрать надписи в коммандной строке после выполнения команды taskkill

Tags: python, ос

Есть скрипт на Python, убивает ненужные процессы, нужно сделать что бы после выполнения команды taskkill не показывалось в консоль сообщение типа `Ошибка: Не удается найти процесс "name.exe".` или `Успешно: Процесс "name.exe", с идентификатором 180, был завершен.`
В скрипте использовалась стандартная библиотека os, завершение процессов выглядело так: `os.system("taskkill /f /im name.exe")`

Comment: Приведите минимальный воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: Для более гибкого управления выводом запускаемого процесса надо использовать функционал модуля [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess)

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess), перенаправив `stdout` и `stderr` в [`subprocess.DEVNULL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.DEVNULL) ("в никуда").

***Пример:***

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.call("taskkill /f /im name.exe", stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно перенаправить потоки вывода в другой файл. Так будет быстрее и короче:

```
import os
os.system("taskkill /f /im name.exe 1> output_file 2>&1")
```